# Apply different addMethod to a field if radio button button seelcted using jQuery validator plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I need to apply different a addMethod to a single field if a certain radio button value is selected.

If the radio button value = true is selected then additional method X should be applied to the field and if the radio button value = false is selected then additional method Y should be applied to the same field.

I have tried accomplishing this sing a conditional statement within a single addMethod, but am not able to display a unique error message for each instance.

```
$.validator.addMethod("RegistrationNumber", function (value, element) { 
  if($("#radio-1").is(":checked")) {
   //opt 1              
  } else {
   //opt 2
  }  
}, "message");

<input type="radio" name="reg" id="radio-1" value="true"/> true
<input type="radio" name="reg" id="radio-2" value="false"/> false
<input type="text" name="RegistrationNumber"/>
```

What are my options here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you please share radio button html too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could have 2 different rules and enable it based on the checked status using `depends` value

```
$.validator.addMethod("RegistrationNumberX", function (value, element) {
    //return true/false based on validation
    return false;
}, "messageX");
$.validator.addMethod("RegistrationNumberY", function (value, element) {
    //return true/false based on validation
    return false;
}, "messageY");
```

then

```
something: {
    RegistrationNumberX: {
        depends: function () {
            return $("#radio").is(":checked")
        }
    },
    RegistrationNumberY: {
        depends: function () {
            return !$("#radio").is(":checked")
        }
    }

}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jvg8v56z/)

Answer (score 0):

//the following code checks if your radio button having name like 'yourRadioName' 
//is checked or not

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($("input:radio[name='yourRadioName']").is(":checked")) {
      //its checked
  }
  else
  {

  }
});
```